# Custom JLabel Cleanup 

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I need to clean my labelResult each time on textField Action, but on the first time it adds 'null' in front of string and then - prints new string right after. Please help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    boolean isDirect = true;
    String[] typeStr = {"direct", "invert"};
    JLabel labelTip = new JLabel("Choose 'direct' OR 'invert' to print your next line in direct order or inverted respectively.");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField("Some text!", 40);
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(typeStr);
    EventProcessing eventProcessing = new EventProcessing();
    JLabel labelResult = new JLabel();

    public Frame() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(labelTip, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        getContentPane().add(comboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        getContentPane().remove(labelResult);
        labelResult = new JLabel();
        labelResult.setText("");
        if (!(comboBox.getSelectedItem()).equals("direct")) {
            isDirect = false;
        }
        else {
            isDirect = true;
        }
        labelResult.setText(eventProcessing.action(isDirect, textField.getText()));
        getContentPane().add(labelResult, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tim I know that in official tutorial about [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) is used `ActionListener`, but for any of actions from JComboBox to the GUI is better look for [ItemListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html), there you are two states (always be called twice, but you can filtering between thes two options SELECTED / DESELECTED by wraping to the if ... else)

and your code should be only

```
Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
      labelResult.setText(eventProcessing.action(isDirect, textField.getText()));
      add(labelResult, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      //1) this.pack(); if you want to re-layout with effect to size of JFrame too

      //2a revalidate(); 
      //2b plus in most cases
      //2b repaint(); relayout Container with fitting JComponents inside Container, 
      //2b but without resize of JFrame
   }
};
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the code to EventProcessing.action() it's hard to determine, but I would guess you attempt to concatenate two strings, the first of which is null. Null strings get converted to the literal string "null."

Comment: it should create new one each time.

Comment: *What* should create a new *what* each time? Each call to `eventProcessing.action()` should create a new `String`?